# How do I create TypeScript diagnostics using the API?

Tags: typescript, typescript-compiler-api

I'm using the TypeScript LanguageService API with custom transformers to mutate an AST. I would like to be able to generate custom diagnostics so I can report errors in a meaningful fashion. How do I do this?

- The CustomTransformer API does not allow reporting diagnostics --- [this appears to be intentional](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/19615).
- The Diagnostics objects themselves do not have any kind of public constructor. (Internally the compiler uses the `ts.createDiagnosticFromNode()` family of functions, but these are marked as internal and aren't in the public API.)
- Neither LanguageService nor TransformationContext look like they've got any hooks to allow me to register a way to create my own diagnostics, or even any way to hook into the compiler so I can walk the AST manually at the appropriate stage if I want to do this myself.

I can't find *any*, that is, not one single reference, to anybody talking about this, apart from the link quoted above. I find it impossible to believe that the TypeScript API doesn't support this, somehow, because producing errors is essentially what compilers are for; which suggests that I'm looking in entirely the wrong place.

So, what *should* I be looking for? How can I do this?

Comment: You've basically linked to the answer—the diagnostics are collected and displayed to the user before emit. That said, there are declaration diagnostics that happen during emit though (related to creating the .d.ts files). So yes, the compiler is about displaying errors, but that doesn't all happen during emit. You could just log out warnings to the user as you see them in your transform or throw an error to stop.

Comment: Sure, but how _do_ I collect and display diagnostics? I cannot find any hooks to let me do this. I can't even _create_ a diagnostic, as the function to do so isn't exported!

Comment: The easiest way is to use the helper `ts.getPreEmitDiagnostics` for getting diagnostics from the program. You might be able to implement your own object that conforms to `ts.Diagnostic` and then display these with the diagnostics from the program by outputting the result of `ts.formatDiagnosticsWithColorAndContext` to the console. Alternatively, just output your own messages to the console alongside these.

Comment: Basically, as stated in that issue [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/19615#issuecomment-340901661), you will need to do this at a higher level than from only within a transform function.

Comment: Yes --- but what _is_ this higher level way? There appear to be no hooks which will let me walk the type-checked tree (let alone the Javascript-transformed tree); there's no way to pass my diagnostics to the compiler for deduplication and aggregation. Right now I have a very interim workaround which involves using a custom `declare` statement to expose `createDiagnosticFromNode()`, and I keep my own list which I generate from `emit` which I merge with the diagnostics from the compiler, but that's so clearly terrible it can't possibly be how it's intended to work.

Comment: Yes, there's no hooks. What you're doing seems reasonable with the current API design other than using `ts.createDiagnosticForNode`... I recommend creating your own `ts.Diagnostic` object or opening an issue on the issue tracker for having helper functions exposed in the public api. By the way, regarding deduplication I would argue it's not worth it for the compiler to perform deduplication of diagnostics when duplicate diagnostics probably shouldn't be generated in the first place.

Comment: Curses. I was really hoping there was something obvious I was missing. Fair enough, I'll file an issue. Thanks.